# Why does Laravel no longer return a response wrapped in an array when more than 2 records are returned?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm having an odd issue with Laravel when returning a response from an endpoint.

When less than two records are returned via my end point I get this response:

[image: endpoint response]

However when that endpoint retrieves more than two records I get the following response:

[image: response in object]

As you can see the json response is now wrapped in an object instead of an array. This is a problem as I am using `var.length` on the client side for this response. It fails when I use `.length` when more than two records are returned as it is returned as an object instead of an array.

Any idea why this might be happening? Here is my controller function that returns the data:

```
/**
 * Return active failures
 */
public function getActiveFailures()
{
  $test_failures_active = TestFailure::where('active', '=', true)
    ->with('type', 'scope', 'error_type')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
  $test_failures_unique = $test_failures_active->unique('error_message');
  return $test_failures_unique;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use `unique` some values from you collection are removed, but keys are staying without changes. As 0-indexed order of keys is broken, `json_encode`ing consider your collection as **object** and not as **array**. What you need to do is to reindex items with [`values()`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-values) method:

```
return $test_failures_unique->values();
```